# Positioning Shape in a filtered sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to design a database, where selecting the name of an item causes a text box to appear containing additional information.
I had it working fine, until I introduced filtering. Because filtering removes some of the rows which are excluded by the filter, the shape no longer appears next to the selected cell, but way down at the position where it would be before the filter.

The code I currently have is:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim strTitle As String
Dim strMsg As String
Dim sTemp As Shape
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsMsg As Worksheet
Dim rngMsg As Range

Application.EnableEvents = False
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set wsMsg = Sheets("BackEnd")
Set sTemp = ws.Shapes("txtInputMsg")
Set rngMsg = wsMsg.Range("SelInList")
On Error Resume Next

wsMsg.Range("SelCell").Value = Target.Address(0, 0)
If Len(rngMsg.Value) > 0 Then
  strMsg = rngMsg.Value
  sTemp.TextFrame.Characters.Text = strMsg
  With ActiveSheet.Shapes("txtInputMsg")
        .Left = Range("A:O").Width + 1
        .Top = Range("1:iActiveCell.Row").Height + 1
  End With
  sTemp.Visible = msoTrue
Else
  sTemp.TextFrame.Characters.Text = ""
  sTemp.Visible = msoFalse
End If

errHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

I tried numerous ways to assign the .Top property of the shape, but I never found a way which worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
With ActiveSheet.Shapes("txtInputMsg")
    .Left = Target.offset,(0,1).left
    .Top = target.top
End With
```

to position the shape exactly at the position of the top right corner of the selected cell. Change the offset or use a fixed column (e.g. `.left = column(7).left`) if that fits you better.